Invalid input 'p' for cypher query with ' CALL apoc.do.when()'
I get the following error for my cypher query (quoted below):
Invalid input 'p': expected 
    'n/N' or 's/S' 
    (line 1, column 116 (offset: 115))

"OPTIONAL MATCH (m:MeasurementSite)-[*2]-(v:Val) 
    WHERE ID(m) = $meter 
    AND v.d < $end 
    AND v.d > $start 
    WITH v, CALL 
        apoc.do.when(v IS NOT NULL, 
            'RETURN abs(toInteger(apoc.temporal.format(duration.inDays($date, $d), \'dd\')))', 
            'RETURN null',
            {d: v.d, date: $date}) AS dist 
    RETURN v, dist;"

The referenced p is the second character in apoc.
Link for CALL is here. Does anybody know the problem and is it related to (wrong) quotes?
Seems like you can start a query with CALL apoc.do.when(), but you cannot use it in somewhere in the middle of a query.
Working on version 4.

The CALL clause cannot be used inside other clauses.
In addition, your WHERE clause effectively filters out v values that are NULL, so:

your query doesn't need to test whether v is NULL, and
your MATCH doesn't need to be OPTIONAL either.

Therefore, this should be good enough:
MATCH (m:MeasurementSite)-[*2]-(v:Val) 
WHERE ID(m) = $meter 
  AND v.d < $end 
  AND v.d > $start
RETURN v, {d: v.d, date: $date} AS dist;


Mmh, I think, this is not always true. What does inside other clauses mean? Consider MATCH (t:Test) WHERE t.location IS NOT NULL CALL apoc.create.vNode(['location'],{value: t.location}) YIELD node RETURN apoc.any.properties(node) AS properties;, which works fine. (a variant of https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.any/apoc.any.properties/#usage-apoc.any.properties) The filtering against not null happens for other reasons: I need the distance to $date later for sorting the results with it. I have refactored the whole thing for avoiding OPTIONAL MATCH.

Actually, I did not get yet, when we need to use CALL for using e.g. apoc.do.when, but when some apoc procedure can be called directly (like apoc.temporal.format).

WITH is a clause. Also, apoc.temporal.format is a function, not a procedure. The CALL clause is used to invoke procedures.

[Clauses] cannot be nested, so a WITH clause cannot contain a CALL clause.
